# iOS UIKeyboard with NO Done button

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

Is it possible to have a UIKeyboard that has no done button in the corner?

If yes, how do I programmatically create it and attatch it to a UITextField?

Thank you very much!

Comment: On the iPhone/iPod touch there are several keyboards with no Done or Return key such as the number pad or phone pad.

Comment: you can change the `returnKeyType` propery anytime.

Comment: No, I don't want to have a done button, I want NO button and still the "normal" keyboard (a-z)

Comment: @Lukas You asked if there can be keyboards with no done button. The answer is Yes - I gave examples in my first comment. You then asked "how do I programmatically create it" where "it" seems to refer to the Done button. We told you how to create the Done button. Since it now seems that what you really wanted to know is if you can create a standard default letter keyboard without the standard Return key (which can be labeled Done or Search or Next in addition to Return, then the answer is no.